# Error : System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to implement this algorithm using `Razor`, but, I got this exception

> *System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

```
@{ 
//....
for (int i = tab[0]; i <= tab[4]; i++)
        {
            if (i == pagination.numPageCourrante)
            {
                <li class="active"><a href="#">@i <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            }
            else
            {//from here the exception triggers
                <li><a href="/Accueil/Rechercher?rech=micro&type=nomAppMetier&num=@(tab[i])">@i </a></li>
            }

        }

}
```

Knowing that the declaration of the table is :

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What are the values inside your tab array? Should your for loop not be for (int i = 0; i <= 4...) By doing tab[0] and tab[4] you are using the values at those indexes.

Comment: Yu must supress = and write tab[4]+1

Comment: The table contains a sequence of 5 integers. According to the debugger, each cell have its right value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your logic is wrong.

What if your `tab[4]` will be `10`? Your loop will work `10` times with this case but your array doesn't have `10` items. That's why probably you get [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your example. `tab[4]` will probably bigger than `4` and that's why your program try to access some index **that your array doesn't have**.

Arrays are zero-indexed. When you define an array with 5 items with;

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
```

You can access items indexed `0` to `4`.

Sounds like you just need to use it like;

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length ; i++)
{
    if (tab[i] == pagination.numPageCourrante)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't want to use the values in the array as start and end of your for-loop. In order to make it work, you can do either of the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
{
    var value = tab[i];
    // use value ...
}
```

Or, you can also use foreach:

```
foreach(int value in tab)
{
    // use value ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your different `i` values are : `tab[0]`, `tab[1]`, `tab[2]`, `tab[3]`, `tab[4]`.

Then when you call `tab[i]` you actually call `tab[tab[x]]`. With x being successively 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Then if any of your `tab` value is not in the interval [0, 4], for example 12, you try to reach `tab[12]` and `IndexOutOFRangeException` is thrown.

It is certainly where the mistake is if you want to simply loop through your array.

The two correct way to do it are with a `for` loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

or with a `foreach` loop :

```
foreach(int i in tab)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u enter like that...u can get the bound error in html array:

here the error happened in name

```
 <td style="width:10%"> @Html.DropDownList("InvoiceUnitID_"+@i, new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitOfMeasures, "Value", "Text", @Model.salesInvoiceVMList[i].InvoiceUnitID), htmlAttributes: new { id = "InvoiceUnitId", name = "InvoiceUnitID"[@i], @disabled="disabled" })</td>
```

instead of that:use like that

```
 <td style="width:10%"> @Html.DropDownList("InvoiceUnitID_"+@i, new SelectList(ViewBag.UnitOfMeasures, "Value", "Text", @Model.salesInvoiceVMList[i].InvoiceUnitID), htmlAttributes: new { id = "InvoiceUnitId", name = "InvoiceUnitID[@i]", @disabled="disabled" })</td>
```